# Aplicación no detiene servicio usando stopService()

Tags: java, android, android-service

Buenas tengo una aplicación que lee los SMS que ingresan a la casilla de mensajes, pero al momento de cerrar dicha aplicación ésta queda en segunda instancia como en modo escucha y me tira un cartel de error cada vez que ingresa otro sms avisando que la aplicación se detuvo. Les comparto el código para ver si me pueden ayudar. Gracias

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

private static SmsListener mListener;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
         Object[] pdus = (Object[]) data.get("pdus");
        System.out.println(" RECIBIO UN NUEVO SMS");
   // for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        // String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();


        // if (sender.equals("GADGETSAINT"))
        //      if (sender.equals((R.string.numeroemisorGPS)))
        //  {
        String numeroEmisor = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress(); // TRAE EL NUMERO DEL REMITENTE SMS
        System.out.println("ESTO TRAE EL ANDRESS DE SMS RECEIVER " + numeroEmisor);
        if (numeroEmisor.length() >= 8) {
            numeroEmisor = numeroEmisor.substring(numeroEmisor.length() - 8);
        }
        // numeroEmisor = numeroEmisor.substring(numeroEmisor.length()-8);
        String cuerpoDelMensaje = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
        System.out.println("ESTO TRAE EL MESSENGERBOCY DE SMS RECEIVER " + cuerpoDelMensaje);
        System.out.println("ESTO TRAE EL ANDRESS DE SMS RECEIVER " + numeroEmisor);
        mListener.messageReceived(cuerpoDelMensaje,numeroEmisor);

        //  }

    }

}

    context.stopService(intent);
}

public static void bindListener(SmsListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    System.out.println(" INGRESA LA BINDLISTENER ");

}
```

}

aca está el Control de Servicios

```
public class ControlDeServicios extends Service {

Context context;

public ControlDeServicios (Context applicationContext) {
    super();
    context = applicationContext;

    System.out.println("INGRESO A LA SERICES");
}

public ControlDeServicios() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    context.startService(intent);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();


}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

y el `manifest.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider" />


<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/motologin_icon"
    android:label="@string/nombre_app"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!--  <activity
          android:name=".LoginActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
        >-->

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrarActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <service android:name=".ControlDeServicios"
        android:enabled="true"
        />



</application>
```

Esta es la parte mas importante del MainActiviy.java

```
    Dialog myDialog;
int cantidadvehiculos = 15;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
```

TextView textBuscando;
    final int PEDIR_PERMISSIONS = 124;
  public static final String INBOX = "content://sms/inbox"; //<- Bandeja de entrada

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDialog = new Dialog(this);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    textBuscando = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textbuscando);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  //ESCONDO EL PROGRESSBAR
    textBuscando.setAlpha(0);



    //final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
    //ELIMINO Y ACTIVO LOS PERMISOS DE LECTURA POR CADA NUEVO SMS QUE INGRESA (LO HICE POR PROBLEMAS CON LOS SAMSUNG)
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},1);


    NavigationView navigationlateral = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationlateral.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(lOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigationlateral.setItemIconTintList(null);

    BottomNavigationView navigationsuperior = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationsuperior);
    navigationsuperior.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigationsuperior.setItemIconTintList(null); //SE UTILIZA PARA QUE LOS ICONOS DEL MENU LATERAL TENGAN EN COLOR POR DESCARTE

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigation.setItemIconTintList(null); //SE UTILIZA PARA QUE LOS ICONOS DEL MENU LATERAL TENGAN EN COLOR POR DESCARTE

    BottomNavigationView navigationinferior = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationinferior);
    navigationinferior.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigationinferior.setItemIconTintList(null); //SE UTILIZA PARA QUE LOS ICONOS DEL MENU LATERAL TENGAN EN COLOR POR DESCARTE


    //      final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
    //      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

    final WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(!myWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Habilitando WIFI!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        myWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

    addMenuItemInNavMenuDrawer();  //MENU LATERAL DE LOS VEHICULOS DISPONIBLES PARA SELECCIONAR

    //private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int sms = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);



    try {
        buscarUbicacion();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,  "No se han encotrado SMS guardados, por favor emita una consulta desde el botón Localizar.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        v.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E74C3C"));
        toast.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (sms == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        System.out.println("Si esta habilitado ");
        try {
            buscarUbicacion();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,  "No se han encotrado SMS guardados por favor emita una consulta desde el botón Localizar.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            v.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E74C3C"));
            toast.show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /****************** PERMISO PARA ENVIAR MENSAJE DE TEXTO ***********/

    int permisoEnviarSms = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);


    if (permisoEnviarSms != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},PEDIR_PERMISSIONS);
        // ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        System.out.println("No esta habilitado ");


        //         return false;

    }else{

        System.out.println("Si esta habilitado ");

    }

    SmsReceiver.bindListener(new SmsListener() {   ///actua cada vez que ingresa un nuevo SMS a la bandeja de entrada

        public void messageReceived(String cuerpoDelMensaje,String numeroEmisor) {

            int iniciolatitud, finlatitud, iniciolongitud, finlongitud, finlongitudS = 0;
            String longitud = "";
            String latitud = "";
            String numeroEmisorGPS = getString(R.string.numeroemisorGPS);
            //   numeroEmisorGPS = numeroEmisorGPS.substring(numeroEmisorGPS.length()-8);
            System.out.println("<----- Estoy en messageReceived y este es el numero que ingresa --> " + numeroEmisor);
            if (numeroEmisor.length() >= 8){
                numeroEmisor = numeroEmisor.substring(numeroEmisor.length()-8);
                numeroEmisorGPS  = numeroEmisorGPS.substring(numeroEmisorGPS.length()-8);
                System.out.println("<-----  Estoy en messageReceived y este es el numero que ingresa pero ACORTADA -----> " + numeroEmisor);
            }
            if (numeroEmisor.equals(numeroEmisorGPS) ) {    // consulto que el numero de emisor que quiero se encuentre en la bandeja de entrada y tomo la partes del mensaje que me interesan.
                iniciolatitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf("lat:") + 4;
                finlatitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf("long");
                iniciolongitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf("long") + 5;
                finlongitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf(",T:");
                finlongitudS = cuerpoDelMensaje.indexOf("speed");
                if (finlongitudS > finlongitud) {
                    latitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.substring(iniciolatitud,finlatitud);
                    longitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.substring(iniciolongitud,finlongitudS);
                } else if ((finlongitudS < finlongitud)) {
                    latitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.substring(iniciolatitud,finlatitud);
                    longitud = cuerpoDelMensaje.substring(iniciolongitud,finlongitud);
                }
                if (iniciolatitud > 4) {
                    final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
                    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=" + latitud.trim() + "," + longitud.trim() + "&z=17");
                    //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    //    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    //    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/erroryaviene.html");
                    //          } });
                    Log.e("ya viene","http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=" + latitud.trim() + "," + longitud.trim() + "&z=16");
                    //   Log.e("ya viene",""+latitud);
                    Log.e("PERMISOS","ingresa al mapa");

                }else { //EN CASO DE QUE EL MENSAJE NO SEA EL DE ACTUALIZAR EL MAPA, MOSTRARÁ DICHO SMS EN UNA VENTANA EMERGENTE
                    TextView txtmensaje;
                    Button btnFollow;
                    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sms_popup);
                    txtmensaje = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtmensaje);
                    txtmensaje.setText(cuerpoDelMensaje);
                    btnFollow = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnfollow);
                    btnFollow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            myDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    myDialog.show();
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  //OCULTO  EL PROGRESSBAR
                textBuscando.setAlpha(0); //OCULTO LA IMAGEN Y TEXTO DEL PROGRESSBAR

            }

        }
    });

}

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Este es el error desde el LOGCAT

```
12-13 15:24:50.034 4769-4769/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ar.com.micronauta.gpscontrol, PID: 4769
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver ar.com.micronauta.gpscontrol.SmsReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void ar.com.micronauta.gpscontrol.SmsListener.messageReceived(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2789)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1468)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void ar.com.micronauta.gpscontrol.SmsListener.messageReceived(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at ar.com.micronauta.gpscontrol.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:45)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2782)
```

Comment: Necesitaría saber donde inicias el servicio? Y cómo lo inicias? para poder ayudarte.

Comment: ese lo tendria que hacer en un archivo aparte? pensé que todo se declaraba en este mismo archivo por eso le puse  context.stopService(intent); . Tal vez lo entendí mal desde el inicio

Comment: Si, necesitas declarar el servicio en el manifest y en algún momento iniciarlo con StartService(intent). Con eso se iniciaría el servicio y después lo podrías parar.

Comment: Amigo, ahi edite la publicación, podrás ver si esta bien?

Comment: @Luis revisa mi respuesta, en realidad detener el servicio desde onReceive() debe ser un poco diferente a como lo estas realizando

Comment: es un problema diferente revisa mi actualización @Luis

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte @Luis , saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para detener el servicio dentro del método `onReceive()`, en lugar de :

```
  context.stopService(intent);
```

Debes usar el método  [stopService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context?hl=es-419#stopService(android.content.Intent)) definiendo el servicio a detener, en este caslo la clase `ControlDeServicios`, ejemplo :

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        context.stopService(new Intent(context, ControlDeServicios.class));

    }
}
```

---

Comentas que obtienes un error, este error se especifica en el LogCat:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   ar.com.micronauta.gpscontrol.SmsListener.messageReceived(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

y se debe a que SmsListener tiene un valor null, te sugiero validar este caso:

```
  if(mListener != null){
     mListener.messageReceived(cuerpoDelMensaje,numeroEmisor);
  }
```

Comment: Gracias amigo. La verdad me sigue tirando error... sinceramente no sè en que parte debo estar fallando.. pongo en MainActivity por las dudas en la publi

Comment: @Luis revisa el LogCat, que error se muestra especificamente?

Comment: ahi actualizo de nuevo y te muestro el error desde el LogCat

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser que el `intent` que le estas pasando no es el del servicio. Prueba a crear un `intent` pasandole la clase que extiende del servicio.

```
Intent sercive = new Intent(this, ControlDeServicios.class);
context.stopService(sercive);
```

Otra opción de la que no estoy muy seguro de que funcione puede ser utilizar lo siguiente.

```
context.stopSelf();
```